# ESAPI for PHP nonexistant?

Tags: php, esapi

I've been trying to find the PHP version of ESAPI for quite a while now but all I can find is a ton of documentation and interfaces. I couldn't find any functioning code at the repository either. Do any finished classes even exist?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [OWASP ESAPI for PHP](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/)

You can view the implementation in the source code repository at [OWASP ESAPI for PHP](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk)

Comment: Yes, but as you can see there are just interfaces there.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a project in the Google Summer of Code to port ESAPI 2 to PHP - also we are always looking for additional contributors to our projects. The current ESAPI4PHP implementation is based off of ESAPI 1.4.x and there are several components that are out of date - however the core components (Output Encoding, Input Validation, Logging, etc) are still applicable and usable - I would recommend using it in the meantime.

You can view the implementation (in addition to the interfaces) in the source code repository at http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

Comment: The Project is no longer accessible via code.google.com Is there a way to export this from SVN to git

Answer (score 0):

There is a github repo:
https://github.com/OWASP/PHP-ESAPI

(but last changed 9 month ago)

Comment: I saw this flagged VLQ and voted "looks ok", since it's only giving what the question asked for. I did vote to close on the question since it's asking for an off-site resource.